# Getting property value of a database with for each statement crashed into a Collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have already searched and all of them errors were caused because they tried to change the values of their own for each element while they were iterating with that element but my code is just adding the items the for each finds to a combobox

```
peliculas = database.getCodigoPelicula() //peliculas is an observable collection of some class
    If peliculas.Any Then
        For Each pelicula In peliculas
            txtCodPel.Items.Add(pelicula.cod_peli)//gets the first code then crashes
        Next pelicula
        txtTitulo.Text = peliculas.ElementAt(0).titulo_peli
    End If
```

Comment: What is `txtCodPel`?

Comment: What do you mean by it crashes? Is an exception thrown? If so, what does it say?

Comment: @preciousbetine: See the title of the question.

Comment: @mm8 it's a textbox on a .xaml

Comment: @preciousbetine exception = "Collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute"

Comment: @preciousbetine sorry it was a combobox i forgot to change its var name, also "my code is just adding the items the for each finds to a combobox"

Comment: @preciousbetine well i cant add items to a textbox, i want to add the property "cod_peli" of all of the objects in the observable  collection "peliculas" to the combobox as items, so "yeah I think so"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
For Each pelicula In peliculas.ToList
        txtCodPel.Items.Add(pelicula.cod_peli)
Next
```

Calling ToList() copies the values of peliculas to a separate list at the start of the for each. Nothing else has access to this list,so nothing can modify it inside the loop.

Comment: Yeah, thanks it worked, but can you explain me why? I want to learn and you would get more upvotes too :)